# How do I adjust and change the size of five subfigures (1st row: 2, 2nd row: 2, last row: 1) so that it fits and is visible to see?

Tags: floats, subcaption

Here is the code I used.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{0.01\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{a.png}
\caption{a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.01\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{a.png}
\caption{a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}\\[1ex]
\begin{subfigure}{0.01\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{a.png}
\caption{a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.01\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{a.png}
\caption{a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}\\[1ex]
\begin{subfigure}{0.01\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{a.png}
\caption{a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{blah blah }
\label{fig:blah}
\end{figure}
```

The figures would appear like this...

[image: Figures in one page]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Your figures are really supposed to be 1/100 linewidth wide? Do you provide the microscope?

Comment: Umm it's actually 0.5 but even I adjusted the linewidth there's no difference.

Comment: I'm afraid you're confusing the figure width and the scale factor (to be used with `\includegraphics`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after correcting sizes of `subfigure` environments and figures to reasonable size, i obtain:

[image]

if `subfigure` width is smaller than image widht in it, than image speall out of `sunfigure`, however, next image start at beginning of the next `subfigure` in the row. therefore, i increase `subfigure` width to `0.45\textwidth` and set the width of included image to width of the `subfigure`:

```
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{...}
```

complete *mwe:*

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}%
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}
\caption{a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}
\caption{a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}
\caption{a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}
\caption{a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}
\caption{a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\caption{blah blah }
\label{fig:blah}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

with real figures in your test you had omit option `demo` at package `graphicx` the heights of figures can changed. in that cases you should add option `height=<desired height>` to `\includegraphics` options. for example

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.25\textheight]{a.png}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked out nice! Is there a way to adjust the size of the caption for the subfigures? The captions for subfigure is too big

Comment: @massmatics, if answer help you to solve your problem, you can accept it :-)  (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer). happy tex-ing!

Comment: @massmatics, regarding caption: if they are long, they will use more line to sit in `subfigure` environment. in its formatting you can exploit capability of `caption` package. fore more, you need to provide example of caption (with edit of your question or better to ask new question) and explain how you like to have it.